# Proving $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

Tags: probability, proof-verification

I am given that X and Y are independent iff $F(x, y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y)$ and are asked to show joint probability $f(x,y)=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

So I think this is an easy proof but I am not sure If it is correct, I did this

$f(x,y)=\frac{\partial ^2}{\partial x\partial y}(F_X(x)F_Y(y))$

$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(F_X(x)f_Y(y))$

$=f_X(x)f_Y(y)$

I think I have seen it some where but I am not sure if $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F_X(x)=f_X(x),\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F_Y(y)=f_Y(y)$ is true.

Comment: What exactly is $f(x,y)$ here? You call it the "joint probability" and treat it as if it is a PDF. But what if there is no PDF? Also it might happen that $F_X$ and/or $F_Y$ is not differentiable.

Comment: @drhab lets assume that they exist for now and is differentiable, with $F(x,y)$ the cdf